# How can I troubleshoot SSD disconnection problems on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, troubleshooting, usb-storage, usb-3

I have a small SSD (Transcend StoreJet TS256GESD200K) which I am using on several computers. The drive is formatted with NTFS and recently I started noticing disconnects.

Normally one probably wouldn't notice (you don't even get the notification sound in Windows when it disconnects), but since I use USBDLM and run a VM from that SSD, I get to see this first-hand.

How could I best figure out whether the problem is the hardware (SSD, USB socket, USB cable or something in the PC) or software?

In short: how can I locate the source of the disruption so that I can work on removing the problem?

Side-note: SMART status for the SSD is clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulate the same conditions with the SSD in question on an entirely separate PC.

If you do have issues on the second PC, it is likely a hardware issue with the SSD.

If you don't have any disconnection issues on another PC, you likely have an issue with the main PC that could still be hardware or software.

At that point you can try emulating the same set up on a second HD or SSD that seemed to cause issues for the primary SSD.

You can also try plugging the SSD into another SATA port on your primary PC's motherboard or try connecting it via a SATA>USB converter.

It could be any number of things but doing those steps should get you a lot closer to the root cause.

In essence: Process of elimination will eventually reveal the culprit but can take a while and become tedious.